# Is there a standard Typescript + Nodejs server boilerplate template?

Tags: node.js, angular, express, typescript

I am developing an Angular2 App and I am trying to build a simple web service for it. Hence I would like to use Typsecript on the server too.

I have looked a bit on the internet about this and found only some blog posts that manually setup Typsecript with Node and Express.

I am wondering if there's a standard boilerplate template that would simply start a project with Typescript and a `Hello World` Webservice in Node (and maybe Express).

EDIT: I guess, a different spin to the question would be: Is there a web framework build for Typescript?

EDIT2: I could not find a proper answer to this, so I ended up moving away from Typescript and going with a full blown framework in [Sails](http://sailsjs.com/) and just using their Javascript version.

Comment: You can use fortjs - http://fortjs.info/ . It is completely built in typescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nodejs Tools for Visual Studio ships with a couple of Express starter templates. Unfortunately they use an old version of Express and are not a good place to start.

The best way to apply TypeScript to any problem is to start with some JavaScript. So any Express template project will do just fine and installing the typings will happen automatically for you if you are using Visual Studio code or a number of  other IDEs.

OR just `npm i --save @types/express`.

Also there's nothing that you gain from using a NodeJS backend with a JavaScript/TypeScript frontend over any other backend technology. The serialization barrier literally does encapsulate them so just use whatever backend makes the most sense.

If you aim to share interface declarations for models,  there are plenty of tools to generate TypeScript from other languages source files.

Comment: Im just trying to build a simple webservice. I think from what I've heard spinning up a Node service should be simpler than other technologies. Hence why I thought it would be a good choice for a micro service.

Comment: If you literally just want an API for testing your application you can use something like npm:json-server which will just let you host files out of an arbitrary directory and make HTTP requests to them. This would be something just for testing but it can't be nice.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/dwyl/hapi-typescript-example

i also started an example sails typoescript app https://github.com/aslanvaroqua/sails-ts

basic gist:

```
/**
 * WelcomeController
 *
 * @description :: Server-side logic for managing Welcomes
 * @help        :: See http://links.sailsjs.org/docs/controllers
 */

import e = require('express');
import util = require('util');

declare const sails: any;

const WelcomeController = {
  index: function (req: e.Request, res: e.Response, next: Function) {
    console.log('index() from WelcomeController.ts');
    sails.models.welcome.find().limit(1).then((welcome) => {
      /// TODO: add logger
      console.log(`welcome page rendering w/ message ${welcome[0].message}`);
      return res.render('welcome', {
        welcome: welcome[0].message
      });
    }).catch((err:Error) => {
      console.error(err.message);
      return res.render('500', err)
    });


  },
  config: function (req: e.Request, res:e.Response, next:Function) {
    console.log('config() from WelcomeController.ts');
    return res.status(200)
      .send('<h1>sails.config :</h1><pre>' + util.inspect(sails.config) + '<pre>');
  }
};

module.exports = WelcomeController;
```

Model

```
export class Welcome {
   attributes: any = {
    id: {
      type: 'integer',
      primaryKey: true
    },
    message: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      defaultsTo: 'default message'
    }
  };
}
```

typings.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "bluebird": "registry:npm/bluebird#3.5.0+20170314181206",
    "connect": "registry:dt/connect#3.4.0+20160510010627",
    "express": "registry:dt/express#4.0.0+20170118060322",
    "express-serve-static-core": "registry:dt/express-serve-static-core#4.0.0+20170324160323",
    "sails": "registry:npm/sails#0.12.0+20160610190623",
    "serve-static": "registry:dt/serve-static#1.7.1+20161128184045"
  },
  "globalDependencies": {
    "es6-shim": "registry:dt/es6-shim#0.31.2+20160726072212",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#7.0.0+20170322231424",
    "socket.io": "registry:dt/socket.io#1.4.4+20170313110830"
  }
}
```

test

```
describe("HashSet", function() {
  it("should behave like a set, removing duplicates", function() {

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a boilerplate template made with Express and TypeScript. Built on top of a minimal working setup, it embodies an Object Oriented implementation of Models, Services and Data Access Objects (DAO's) using Mongoose and Inversify:

https://github.com/omerg/express-mongodb-base

If you have a J2EE programming background with Spring MVC and Hibernate, the structure of the project should be very familiar.

The project is ready to deploy to Heroku. All you have to do is to set environment variables for Heroku and MongoDb.

There are some other paradigms that the project mention such as Containerization and CI/CD. Contributions are welcome! :)

Answer (score 0):

*FWIW: This doesn't directly answer the question but may be helpful as a supplemental answer.*

Stephen Grider's Udemy course, [Typescript: The Complete Developer's Guide](https://www.udemy.com/course/typescript-the-complete-developers-guide/), contains around 3.5 hours of content specifically geared towards integrating TS with Express.

It provides boilerplate and includes some deep dives into a number of integration issues that devs may encounter in the process (such as with CORS, bodyParser, etc).

I took the course myself and learned a lot, so I thought I'd share here in case it may be helpful to others.

(Note: I'm not getting incentivized to post this in any way; I simply found the course to be helpful.)